# Ruby Logger to add context information on each line

Tags: ruby, logging

What happens:

```
$logger.info("progname"){"msg_line1\nmsg_line2"}
I, [2017-03-16T14:14:01.426134 #846807]  INFO -- progname: msg_line1
msg_line2
```

What I'd like to achieve:

```
$logger.info("progname"){"msg_line1\nmsg_line2"}
I, [2017-03-16T14:14:01.426134 #846807]  INFO -- progname: msg_line1
I, [2017-03-16T14:14:01.426134 #846807]  INFO -- progname: msg_line2
```

What I tried already:

```
$logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
original_formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
$logger.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
   msg.each_line do |line|
     original_formatter.call(severity, datetime, progname, line)
   end
 }
```

What happend:

```
$logger.info("progname"){"msg_line1\nmsg_line2"}
msg_line1
msg_line2=> true
```

Can somebody help me out? I don't know why my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [formatter `proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#attribute-i-formatter) should return a string, not just delegate method calls to another formatter.

Right now, your `proc` returns the content of `msg.each_line` :

```
msg_line1
msg_line2
```

You could check that the formatter does the job correctly by adding `p` before `original_formatter.call(...`. It's just that you don't use the results.

Here's a modified version of your code :

```
require 'logger'

$logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
original_formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
$logger.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
  msg.split("\n").map do |line|
    original_formatter.call(severity, datetime, progname, line)
  end.join
}

$logger.info('progname') { "msg_line1\nmsg_line2" }
# I, [2017-03-16T15:08:40.688193 #5372]  INFO -- progname: msg_line1
# I, [2017-03-16T15:08:40.688193 #5372]  INFO -- progname: msg_line2
```